# Laravel queue And Azure WebJob

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-webjobs, laravel-queue, azure-appservice

I have a Laravel project in Azure App Service ..
I'm using Laravel queue to run long jobs in the background, so I've added a WebJob to run the queue .. the problem is the jobs execute sequentially and not parallelly.

After searching I found that I need a supervisor to run multiple workers.

My question is how can I run multiple workers to run the same queue in Azure??

My continuous WebJob:

```
php %HOME%\site\wwwroot\artisan queue:listen --timeout=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understand of the issue. Continuous Job runs on all instances that the web app runs on. Indeed, you can optionally restrict the WebJob to a single instance (different in your case).

Note that App Service will only look for a script under the root directory of that job (not under sub directories of it). Only these are supported file types for scripts or programs are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/webjobs-create):

Laravel, uses the public/ subdirectory as the site root.

Jobs are deployed by copying them to d:\home\site\wwwroot as illustrated below. These Jobs will run under the worker process of the SCM\Kudu Web Site and not the main site.

Path : wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous{job name}).

To set a continuous job as singleton during deployment then you can simply create a file called settings.job with the content: { "is_singleton": true } and put it at the root of the (specific) WebJob directory. However, in your case { "is_singleton": false }

If your requirement fits you can use [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) or [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#compare-functions-and-webjobs)